# Simplify Matrix Expression, and General Tips For Simplifying Matrix Expressions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

this is a step in my Textbook *Deep Learning* when talking about Bayesian Linear Regression, but the context is not too important.

I'm wondering how the author goes about simplifying from 5.75 to 5.76. I'm not too familiar on how to expand certain matrix-vector products, and I've been getting similar things as him but not the exact same.

[image]

I *thought* I was able to expand the $(y-Xw)^T(y-Xw)$ term, which I *thought* expands into $(y^Ty + w^TX^TXw)$. The $w^TX^TXw$ term is there in the expansion, but I don't understand where the $-2y^TXw$ term comes from.

I don't really know what to do with the next part.

I was wondering if someone could help me out to see why the matrix and vectors simplify like that, and maybe give a few in-general tips to simplifying matrix expressions in general? I can't seem to find any helpful resources on it and I run into them quite a bit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analagous to $(a-b)^2 = a^2 - 2ab + b^2$, we have
$$(y-Xw)^\top (y-Xw) = y^\top y - 2y^\top X w + w^\top X^\top X w.$$

Similarly,
$$(w-\mu)^\top \Lambda^{-1} (w-\mu) = w^\top \Lambda^{-1} w - 2 \mu^\top \Lambda^{-1} w + \mu^\top \Lambda^{-1} \mu.$$

As SoufHay noted, terms that don't involve $w$ can be considered constants, and can be thrown away by being absorbed into the proportionality symbol $\propto$.

Answer (score 1):

If you simplify the two products, you'll have some terms that don't depend on $w$, you can get rid of those since they are constants, and we're using just the $\propto$ symbol and not the $=$ symbol.